# How can I change the size of my images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the size of the images that I have in my footer but everytime that I try to change the image size in my footer it always get the code from the profile image. What did I forget to do?

```
<img src="marcos.jpg">

img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;  
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

<footer>
    <div id="firstDiv">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/marcos-freire/">
     <img src="linkedin.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="secondDiv">
     <a href="https://github.com/mfreire1996">
     <img src="github.png">
      </a>
    </div>
</div>



    </div>
</footer>

#firstDiv {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#secondDiv {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: What "profile image"? What "code" does it get?

Answer (score 0):

set the height or the width side then set the other 
side  auto.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that your CSS attributes for  are over-writing the CSS attributes that you have set for #firstDiv and #secondDiv.

Please use the developer tools in IE / Chrome to get a better picture.

Answer (score 0):

**Check Libraries**
Sometimes people add 3rd party scripts which hijack styling, I recently saw one with an employer of mine who used a calendar script and used bootstrap and this of cause has a load of pre-set styles which over-rode the ones from our company website, the styles mainly applied to HTML Selectors.

**CSS**
Try adding the !Important tag to the height and width of your image
CSS rules dictate that the following order takes precidence:

Browser Stylesheet
user Stylesheet
author Stylesheet
HTML stylesheet

It will then decide from the stylesheets it has that precise CSS takes presidence over other CSS

Highest Priority
Inline CSS 
ID 
Class
HTML Selector
Lowest Priority

Ultimately this can be overriden with the !important psuedo

```
img#profile{
  height: 250px!important;
  width: 100px!important;
}
```

should do it